# Using Azure Mobie Service .Net backend for push only

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I'm making Azure background worker role for push and many other jobs.

Unlike [Azure Push Notification Hub example](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-send-breaking-news/) to send raw JsonPayload strings, Azure Mobile Service(a.k.a ZUMO) library provides more concreate and handy function for push.

For example, [this document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/04/08/push-notifications-using-notification-hub-and-net-backend.aspx) introduces how to send GCM push as below.

```
GooglePushMessage message = new GooglePushMessage();
message.Data.Add("greeting", "Hello World!");
message.DelayWhileIdle = true;
message.TimeToLiveInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 2;
message.Add("myKey1", "myValue");
await Services.Push.SendAsync(message);
```

In short, I'd like to use the `GooglePushMessage : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Notifications.IPushMessage` class to send a push. It looks useful for iOS and WNS also.

My problem is, the `Services` requires initialization but its hard to find which configurations should be given. The auto-generated sample sources from Azure portal provides lots of `MS_` settings which may or may not usable for me in web.config.

The basic initialization code of `Services` could be similar as below, but how to do correctly?

```
ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();
HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));
ApiServices Services = new ApiServices(config);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the service bus library from NuGet. It has a namespace for managing notification hubs and sending notifications using either platform specific notification classes or more generic methods (for use with templates.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.notifications.aspx

I'll admit it doesn't currently have as many nice helper methods, but it's a little better than strings of JSON for everything.

I'd recommend using templates with notification hubs, especially if you expect to have more than one client platform as it enables you to send raw data and have the clients dictate, through their template, how they want to receive that data and display it. For example, you might have the Android handle the message as an alert and then have IOS display a badge or put a notification in the notification center. On Windows/WinPhone you can do tile updates or toast all driven from the same raw data you send to the notification hub.

The Azure Mobile Services stuff is only going to work hosted in an Azure mobile service in many cases because their runtime injects some of those services for you. It's possible you could get it working, but it was/is intended to work hosted in an Azure mobile service. That's part of the value add.

All that said, you could setup an Azure Mobile Service and have it just host the push notification aspect. Then you could interact with it through a custom API (just add a regular ASP.NET Web API controller) to invoke the push notifications. Or put your scheduled work related to push notifications in a mobile service scheduled job instead of a worker role.

Comment: I like your last idea of using a simple AMS just to leverage the easy push integration. But if you use a Node/JavaScript backend it'll be even easier to call the REST API without requiring any WebAPI work.